# PhpStorm подсвечивает тесты

Tags: php, phpstorm, symfony3

В общем перешли на 3-ю symfony тесты соответственно выехали из бандлов. Сейчас подсвечивает во всех тестах методы phpunit \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase - не видит шторм. Так тесты работают нормально.

Comment: может подцепить тесты как external library?

Comment: пришлось выкачать в отдельную папку сурсы phpunit и подключить отдельно

Comment: можно добавить в composer.json `"symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0", "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.2"`. чтобы не мусорить продакшен, не в require, а в require-dev

Comment: Он там есть, ещё со 2-й версии

Answer (score 1):

- Для подсветки вы можете скачать .phar архив с [официального сайта](https://phpunit.de) и положить его в корень.
- или вы можете установить phpunit через PEAR, но это вроде уже не рекомендуемый способ
- или же вы можете в composer.json прописать в require-dev зависимость phpunit